# Is there any reason why the Profunctor instance of (->) defines both dimap and lmap/rmap?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, arrows, profunctor

In the [source code on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/src/Data.Profunctor.Unsafe.html#line-189) I read this:

```hs
instance Profunctor (->) where
  dimap ab cd bc = cd . bc . ab
  {-# INLINE dimap #-}
  lmap = flip (.)
  {-# INLINE lmap #-}
  rmap = (.)
  {-# INLINE rmap #-}
```

but the default implementations of `dimap`/`lmap`/`rmap` for the `Profunctor` would require one to just define either both `lmap` and `rmap`, or `dimap`; defining all of them is unnecessary.

Is there a reason why they are all defined, instead?

Comment: Though both `rmap` and `lmap` can in always be defined in terms of `dimap` in principle, sometimes a more efficient implementation exists. That's why they're methods of the class in the first place, and not standalone functions.

Answer (score 3):

As @FyodorSoikin comments, the intention was probably that the `lmap` and `rmap` hand-coded definitions would be more efficient than the default definitions based on `dimap`.

However, using the test program below, I tried defining the instance with all three of `dimap`/`rmap`/`lmap`, `dimap` only, and `rmap`/`lmap` only, and the core for the test functions `l`, `r`, and `b` was precisely the same in all three cases when compiled with `-O2`:

```
b = \ x -> case x of { I# x1 -> I# (+# 15# (*# 6# x1)) }
r = \ x -> case x of { I# x1 -> I# (+# 15# (*# 3# x1)) }
l = \ x -> case x of { I# x1 -> I# (+# (*# x1 2#) 5#) }
```

While it's possible that for more complicated examples the compiler will fail to optimize the default definitions of `lmap f = dimap f id` and `rmap = dimap id`, it strikes me as exceedingly unlikely, and so the hand-coded `lmap` and `rmap` don't make any  difference.

I think the explanation is that even extremely skilled Haskell programmers like Edward Kmett still underestimate the compiler and perform unnecessary hand-optimizations of their code.

*Update:*  In a comment, @4castle asked what happens without optimization.  With the caveat that "because it improves `-O0` code" doesn't strike me as a sound argument for *anything*, I took a look.

In unoptimized code, the explicit `rmap` definition produces better Core by avoiding an extra composition with `id`:

```
-- explicit `rmap`
r = . (let { ds = I# 3# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds)
      (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds)

-- default `rmap`
r = . (let { ds = I# 3# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds)
  (. (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds) id)
```

while the explicit `lmap` definition ends up producing Core that's about the same, or arguably worse.

```
-- explicit `lmap`
$clmap = \ @ a @ b1 @ c -> flip .
l = $clmap
      (let { ds = I# 2# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds)
      (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds)

-- default `lmap`
l = . id
      (. (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds)
         (let { ds = I# 2# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds))
```

As a consequence of the above definitions, the explicit `dimap` is better than the default because of the extra `flip`.

```
-- explicit `dimap`
b = . (let { ds = I# 3# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds)
      (. (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds)
         (let { ds = I# 2# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds))

-- default `dimap`
$clmap = \ @ a @ b1 @ c -> flip .
b = . ($clmap (let { ds = I# 2# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds))
      (. (let { ds = I# 3# } in \ ds1 -> * $fNumInt ds1 ds))
      (let { ds = I# 5# } in \ ds1 -> + $fNumInt ds1 ds)
```

In another comment, @oisdk scolded me for my unrealistic test.  I will point out that failure to inline recursion isn't really an issue here, since none of `dimap`, `lmap`, or `rmap` is recursive.  In particular, simply "using" one of these in a recursive manner, like `foo = foldr rmap id` doesn't interfere with inlining or optimization, and the generated code for `foo` is the same with the explicit and default `rmap`.

Also, splitting the class/instance from the `l`/`r` definitions into separate modules makes no difference to my test program, nor does splitting it up into three modules, the class, the instance, and `l`/`r`, so it doesn't seem like inlining across module boundaries is much of a problem here.

For unspecialized polymorphic usage, I guess it'll come down to the `Profunctor (->)` dictionary that's generated.  I see the following which seems to show that an explicit `dimap` with default `lmap` and `rmap` produces better code than the alternatives.  The problem seems to be that `flip (.)` isn't being properly optimized here, so the explicit `lmap` definition is counterproductive.

```
-- explicit `dimap`, `rmap`, and `lmap`
$fProfunctor->
  = C:Profunctor $fProfunctor->_$cdimap $fProfunctor->_$clmap .
$fProfunctor->_$cdimap
  = \ @ a @ b @ c @ d ab cd bc x -> cd (bc (ab x))
$fProfunctor->_$clmap = \ @ a @ b @ c x y -> . y x

-- explicit `lmap`, `rmap`, default `dimap`
$fProfunctor->
  = C:Profunctor $fProfunctor->_$cdimap $fProfunctor->_$clmap .
$fProfunctor->_$cdimap
  = \ @ a @ b @ c @ d eta eta1 x eta2 -> eta1 (x (eta eta2))
$fProfunctor->_$clmap = \ @ a @ b @ c x y -> . y x

-- explicit `dimap`, default `lmap`, `rmap`
$fProfunctor->
  = C:Profunctor
      $fProfunctor->_$cdimap $fProfunctor->_$clmap $fProfunctor->1
$fProfunctor->_$cdimap
  = \ @ a @ b @ c @ d ab cd bc x -> cd (bc (ab x))
$fProfunctor->_$clmap = \ @ a @ b @ c eta bc x -> bc (eta x)
$fProfunctor->1 = \ @ b @ c @ a cd bc x -> cd (bc x)
```

If someone has an example where these explicit definitions generate better `-O2` code, it would make a great alternative answer.

Here's my test program.  I compiled with `ghc -O2 Profunctor.hs -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques`.

```
module Profunctor where

class Profunctor p where
  dimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p b c -> p a d
  dimap f g = lmap f . rmap g
  {-# INLINE dimap #-}

  lmap :: (a -> b) -> p b c -> p a c
  lmap f = dimap f id
  {-# INLINE lmap #-}

  rmap :: (b -> c) -> p a b -> p a c
  rmap = dimap id
  {-# INLINE rmap #-}

instance Profunctor (->) where
  -- same core if dimap is commented out or if lmap/rmap are commented out
  dimap ab cd bc = cd . bc . ab
  lmap = flip (.)
  rmap = (.)

l :: Int -> Int
l = lmap (*2) (+5)

r :: Int -> Int
r = rmap (*3) (+5)

b :: Int -> Int
b = dimap (*2) (*3) (+5)
```

Comment: What if optimizations are not enabled? (no `-O2` flag)

Comment: The example program you have is really quite a poor test of inlining: it's all a single module (inlining in particular works best when you don't cross module boundaries), there's no recursion (which often GHC can't inline around), and there are no polymorphic functions (i.e. ones that refer to the `Profunctor` class abstractly, rather than just using the functions). In real code, I would absolutely expect this hand-optimisation to yield a speedup. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jI-AlWEwYI) talk is quite good at debunking some of the myths surrounding what inlining GHC can do.

Comment: One interesting thing is always to see what `-ddump-simpl -O` produces in each case, including inlining and inlining guidance.